# Setting re-ordering property of a cell to NO

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

Can we specifically set the re-ordering property of a cell (Add cell with + button) to NO? I cannot set editingStyle to NO as then I would not get even the + button in Add cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the delegate method: `tableView:canMoveRowAtIndexPath:`.

You should use it by checking to see what the indexPath is and then return NO if the indexPath is the indexPath of a cell you do not want reorderingEnabled on.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a cell's `showsReorderControl` to `NO`, implement `tableView:moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:`and return `NO` for `tableView:canMoveRowAtIndexPath:`.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableViewCell/showsReorderControl